# How to remove orphans qTips?

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I'm using qTip2... I have a pretty Drupal form with Ajax.

When I update the form with Ajax some elements go away... and some of them had a qTip.

After that one or many orphan qTips will run to the left corner of my screen.

I want to remove the orphan qTips.

How can I make them disappear once their referenced elements are gone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know what elements are going to leave the page, you can call qtip("destroy" on them before you remove them.

```
$("#tooltipElement").qtip('destroy', true);
```

You could create a function that does this for you and call it within a loop:

```
function DestroyQtip(element) {
    element.qtip('destroy', true);
}

for (i = 0; i < someListOfTooltips.length; i++)
{
    DestroyQtip(someListOfToolTips[i]);
}
```